# 'Dem ist nicht so' - or - 'Das ist nicht so'?

Tags: grammaticality

I had always thought that the dative should be used in this expression. But it seems that I have increasingly seen *Das ist nicht so*. Example in a comment in *ZON* 31.07.2019:

> ..diese Formulierung liest sich, als wären 2/3 der Studien mangels
> Fakten nicht zu einer tragfähigen Aussage gelangt. *Das ist aber nicht
> so*.
>
> [Zehn Fakten zum Klimawandel](https://www.zeit.de/wissen/umwelt/2018-11/klimagipfel-in-katowice-klimawandel-fakten-mythen-globale-erwaermung-wissenschaft) - (Comments page 71)

Is this a question of formality (*das ist nicht so* being more informal). Or is *das ist nicht so* considered ungrammatical?

Comment: @David Vogt. Thanks for the tip. Maybe the search function on this site is not working properly since I had tried to see if this issue had been addressed already. The only other question the search returned explained why the dative is used, but didn't refer to the non-dative version: https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22dem+ist+nicht+so%22.